# Why video served through CGI is not played by the browser

Tags: python, google-chrome, cgi, html5-video

I'm trying to create a Python CGI that loads videos from a hidden location in my server and "prints" that video to stdout so a HTTP client could get it's content.

Here is my python CGI script:

```
import os
import sys

filePath = "test_video.mp4"

print "Last-Modified: Fri, 24 Apr 2015 22:09:52 GMT"
print "Accept-Ranges: bytes"
print "Content-Length:", os.path.getsize(filePath)
print "Content-type: video/mp4\n"
sys.stdout.flush()
content = file(filePath, "rb").read()
sys.stdout.write(content)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

When I open the link that points to the video, with Google Chrome, for example (http://192.168.0.4/~fccoelho/mpeg/test_video.mp4) the video is played perfectly. However when I open (http://192.168.0.4/~fccoelho/mpeg/test.py) that is the CGI script for serving the same file, the video is not played.

What is odd is that when I get both with wget, the served file is exactly the same.

I have also checked the headers with curl:

```
curl -I http://192.168.0.4/~fccoelho/mpeg/test.py

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 24 Apr 2015 23:09:34 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Last-Modified: Fri, 24 Apr 2015 22:09:52 GMT
Content-Length: 32445874
Content-Type: video/mp4

curl -I http://192.168.0.4/~fccoelho/mpeg/test_video.mp4

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 24 Apr 2015 23:09:55 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Fri, 24 Apr 2015 22:09:52 GMT
ETag: "1ef15b2-5147fa7cfbd80"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 32445874
Content-Type: video/mp4
```

And they seem to be compatible.
Could someone give a clue on why this approach is not working?

I have tried everything here in Firefox and it works.
But what scares me is how Google Chrome can behave differently even receiving the same response.

Comment: it is bad think to serve video content  with *.py extension, some hooks to this extension could be present in the browser and prevent detection by MIME type(by add-ins for example). Use url rewriters on servers side and access you script like this is video file (mp4)